# XY-Pic: Make fractions appear as in displayed math

Tags: xy-pic

When writing diagrams with XY-Pic, fractions appear as if they were math enclosed in `$$`.
Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xy}
\begin{document}
\begin{xy}
(0,0)*{\frac{d_1}{d_2}};
\end{xy}
\end{document}
```

The actual diagram I am working at is of course more complicated, and these fractions appear too cramped.
How can I enforce the fraction to appear as in displayed math, that is, as in `\[ \frac{d_1}{d_2} \]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`. This macro is available using the package `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

There is as well a macro `\tfrac` available.

The letter `d` stays for `\displaystyle`, and `t` for `\textstyle`.